# Ruby return only date older than 2 days ago - undefined method `days' for 2:Integer

Tags: ruby

I array below I want to get only days which are older than 2.days.ago

```
data = ["2020-02-21T07:52:14.114+0100",
 "2020-02-19T13:20:50.539+0100",
 "2020-02-11T12:36:16.565+0100",
 "2020-02-17T20:06:53.312+0100",
 "2020-02-04T09:42:30.754+0100",
 "2020-01-29T13:46:16.033+0100",
 "2020-02-18T11:15:12.894+0100"]
```

I'm trying to do this with code below:

`data.select { |data| data if DateTime.parse(data) > 2.days.ago }`

But I'm getting an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `days' for 2:Integer

Comment: `n.days.ago` is a syntax that's introduced in Rails. So you have to use `activesupport` gem to use it.

Comment: Damn, so the only way is to use some ugly syntax like `data.select { |data| data if DateTime.parse(data) > (Time.now-2*24*60*60).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }` am I right? `activesupport` sound like a heavy gem, I don't thinks it will be useful if I need this in one line - my aws lambda won't like it

Comment: As you can see from the comments on the lone answer to date there is confusion about your question. If `t` is the current time (for the given time zone) and `d` is the current day, do you wish to select those strings whose corresponding `DateTime` objects,  a) fall before two days prior to day `d`; b) fall before 48 hours before time `t`; or c) fall before time `t` on the date two days prior to `d`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others already pointed out in the comments, `n.days.ago` is not part of plain Ruby but is introduced with Ruby on Rails (see docs about [`days`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-days) and [`ago`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-ago)).

The equivalent to `n.day.ago` in plain Ruby might be something like this:

```
 Time.now - n * 24 * 60 * 60
```

That means when you want to select dates that are older than 2 days, then you can write your example like this:

```
 two_days_ago = Time.now - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60
 data.select { |data| Time.parse(data) < two_days_ago }
```

Please note, there is no need for the `date if` part in the `select` block.

Comment: Or, maybe, using `Date` class would be valid in this case? It can be compared with `DateTime` instances and `Date.today - 2` looks way better.

Comment: I am not sure if that would work for the OP, depends on the context. Because the OP is dealing with instances of Time I guess the OP wants to check against _the same time but two days ago_ and not _beginning of the day two days ago_.

Comment: It has to be `DateTime` - without this it returns all values in my app. Funny fact - I have to put this in `select` condition - `project.select { |issue| (...) && DateTime.parse(issue.fields.dig('pending')) < TWO_DAYS` - this will return desired values (issues updated more than 2 days ago). Do you know why? I think it should worked If I use `>` instead of `<` or am I wrong? lol

Comment: That is correct, when you want to select records that are older than 2 days ago then you need to select dates that are smaller (`<`) than the time two days ago. Why does it have to be `DateTime`? Since Ruby 2.0 `Time` has the same range and it is preferred because its implementation is simpler.

Comment: Note that "the same time but two days ago" is not the same as "48 hours ago". There is no guarantee that a day has 24 hours. (On daylight savings change, a day has 23 or 25 hours.) Similarly, "48 hours ago" is not the same as "172800 seconds ago. (Because of leap seconds, an hour may have 3599 or 3601 seconds.)